# php bin/console make:crud has bugs in it when i try to create new

Tags: symfony, doctrine

i create a crud in console

```
    php bin/console make:crud Location
```

It works fine.  I go to `/location/`

[image: PHP error]

Click create new and i get this sql error

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT e0_.id AS id_0, e0_.created AS created_1, e0_.updated AS updated_2, e0_.updated_by_id AS updated_by_id_3, e0_.type AS type_4, p1_.name AS name_5, p1_.email AS email_6, e0_.created_by_id AS created_by_id_7, e0_.permission_id AS permission_id_8, p1_.relationships_id AS relationships_id_9, p1_.locations_id AS locations_id_10 FROM people p1_': SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e0_.id' in 'field

Its as if there are two tables there.  please help.

Below is the `location` class.  It includes `people` in it.  Created by is a `person`.  I dont know if i have the mapping correct im very new to `Symfony`.

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class Location
 * @package App\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity() 
 * @ORM\Table("locations")
 */
class Location
{

     /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
     protected $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
    */
    protected $created;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
    */
    protected $updated;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Person")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    protected $createdBy;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Permission")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="permission_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    protected $permissions;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="updated_by_id")
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Person")
    */
    protected $updatedBy;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(length=255)
    */
    private $name;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $address;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(length=255)
    */
    private $geoSpatial;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Person")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $createdBy;
```

created by needed to be mapped properly.  i am such a ninny!

Thanks for the person that noticed "where is people coming from" that helped me, sometimes you cant see stuff in your own code!

Answer (score 0):

- be sure that there is no existing table with the same name in the same database
- be sure that you update your database schema after that you create or change entities. If you want to follow the docs you will have to use the migrations but if you would like to make the changes immediately you can do

```
bin/console doctrine:schema:update: --force
```

Warning: do not use this command in a production environment!

Answer (score 0):

What is this `people` entity ? The query is on this table, not `Location`

Comment: created_by_id is a people entity

Comment: i removed created by and it works.  might have something to do with my mapping.

Comment: Your query seems incomplete. It ends with `FROM people p1_`. `e0_` comes from nowhere. You should have a `JOIN`.

Comment: The error come from `e0_.id` because it is the first reference to `e0_` and it doesn't know what it is.

Comment: Is `people` the table name of the `Person` entity ?

Comment: Please update your main question : update Location and add Person